# MVC - Serve an index.html + bundle.js created by react

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, reactjs, model-view-controller, routes

my question may not be related to react directly and maybe related to MVC routes only but i decided to share the bigger picture if anyone thinks i'm on the wrong track.
we have a React / redux application that bundles to an `index.html` file with `css` and `js` resources:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Booking Engine</title>
    <link href="./main.837f1985001f2e603b8755f0f28be780.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>
    <div id="sb-be"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./main.adb11750acf05df99619.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

the resources are dynamicly hashed as you can see.
I need to serve this `index.html` from a MVC application, i tried to do that using [this](https://howtoember.wordpress.com/2016/06/04/using-react-router-with-asp-net-mvc/) post (by using MapPageRoute and RouteExistingFiles in RouteConfig).
I can serve the html as expected, though the resources are not being served correctly.
This is my file structure in my MVC app:

```
--MVCRoot    
----Other MVC related folders  
----ReactFolder  
--------dist  
------------index.html  
------------main[hash].js  
------------main[hash].css
```

now using a `MapPageRoute` like so:

```
    routes.MapPageRoute("index", "SomeName/{*pathInfo}", "~/ReactFolder/dist/index.html");
```

The resource files of `main.js` and `main.css` are being served as the `index.html`, i mean i literally get the index.html instead of the actual js and css files.
I tried with `routes.RouteExistingFiles` set to `true` or `false` but no help.

EDIT: basically my question is how to serve a `html` static file with a "pretty" (custom) URL without interrupting the page's resources load with their relative path?

Comment: why don't you copy the react dist files to your mvc folders?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: you can use something like the 'copyfiles' node dependency to copy your index.html, js and css file to a folder in the mvc app to be served from there

Comment: but __it is__ in the mvc app. see my structure again, it's inside the root of my mvc app (inside a folder of react/dist/...)